How do i use both GPU's in Aurora Linux?
I am a new linux user and was running 5 monitors on 2 GPU's, I recently switched to Aurora Linux, on booting it recognizes only the NVidia GPU. is there a way to correct this to use the other GPU as well? I currently have 3 monitors on the nvidia card, and 2 on the AMD gpu on the motherboard.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
